# Python Selenium Dropdown list Clickable : AGAIN

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, webdriver-io

I want to scrap investing.com website. Firefox Webdriver closes when clicking on one of the dropdown list item. Dropdown menu is hiidden. I want to choose "BİST Ulusal Tüm" item. What can i do?

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
url = "https://tr.investing.com/equities/turkey"
driver.get(url)
driver.implicitly_wait(5)
WebDriverWait(driver, 1).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="index-select"]'))).click()
WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="index-select"]/div[2]/div/div/div[6]'))).click()
```

No popup, No errors,  Just close Firefox Webdrive. Only, Debug last line in below;

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="index-select"]/div[2]/div/div/div[6]'))).click()
```

Hoop close Firefox webdrive.

Please help!!!!

I tried everything, it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

Check the below refactored code:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
url = "https://tr.investing.com/equities/turkey"
driver.get(url)
driver.maximize_window()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)

# Click on I Accept pop-up
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[text()='I Accept']"))).click()

# Click on dropdown
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@id='index-select']"))).click()

# Click on BİST Ulusal Tüm
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[text()='BİST Ulusal Tüm']"))).click()
```

Result:

[image]